# Cookie в мобильном приложении на HTML5.

Tags: cookie, html5

Итак, делаю мобильное приложение на HTML5 с последующей компиляций в сервисе PhoneGAP. Столкнулся с проблемой запоминания/чтения куков для локального файла.

Как решается данный вопрос - Web Storage и ни каких куков?

Comment: Ничего удивительного. Запускайте index.html не из файла, а из сервера на localhost, например python'ом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В комьюнити PhoneGAP](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/cookie_support_in_android_4_0_using_phonegap_build) рекомендуют localStorage или WebSQL. Вообще-то говоря, сам не пробовал, но и web storage по идее должен работать.

Comment: Вполне не плохо пашет) спс